# What is a proper server for this website

Tags: php, performance, hosting, zend-framework

We are using zend framework, doctrine on our website, that will have the minimum of 2000 users daily, please consider that we prefer that the server has opcode caching.
And any available technology that speeds up php performance.
We have heard that zend server offers an optimal performance for php.
Please recommend a hosting server or a vps plan, that can handle such an application.
given that our application has some kind of social networking and it applies alot of ajax requests even in minimal usage of the website, for example in 30 min we may have up to 400 requests from an individual user.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

it really depends pretty heavily on what your software does, and the databases behind it.

If you just want a system to throw it on and not have to worry about it, i'd probably start with a cluster.

```
2 Load Balancers (HA) / 3 Web Servers (HP/HA) / 2 Backend Servers (HA)
```

other then something like that your system will be pretty heavily dependant upon the application.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how your application is architected, what sort of average request completion times you're seeing, etc. it is pretty much impossible to make any kind of sane recommendation.  What you need to do it pick an architecture to use as a starting point, deploy, then run load tests against it.  See where the bottlenecks are and address them one-by-one until you run out of places to optimize.  Then you can determine if the platform you selected will be enough to meet your needs and allow some room to grow.  If the load test doesn't pass your requirements on that platform, move up to something larger and try again.  The key is to validate your decisions.  Given your application you may find that a shared VPS might be enough, or you may need multiple servers with load balancing.  From the numbers it would seem to me that one server would do the trick, but your applications are likely built way different from mine.

Answer (score 1):

> that will have the minimum of 2000
>   users daily

Äh? Sorry, but under most applications (you dont say anything specific) this is "the server does nothing pretty much all of the time, and if it does not do nothing it bores to death.

2000 users daily is like 3-4 users at the same time, spike around 8-10. Cheap virtual server.

> for example in 30 min we may have up
>   to 400 requests from an individual
>   user

New definition of "A lot." 10 concurrent users = 4000 requests in 30 minuts. Impresive?

Maybe, unless you use simple maths. 4000 requets / 30 minutes / 60 seconds = 2.22 requests per second. Server does nothing level.

Comment: Can you offer any transaction baselines for typical "cheap virtual server"? 50 req/sec, 150, req/sec?

Comment: Depends a lot on the logic behind it... but in general.... definitely higher than single digit. I would possibly get "not totally cheap" once I hit more than 10 per second.